# Linked-list java implementation error?

Tags: java

So I wanna keep it short. I have implemented Linked-list and Node class in java. Inside node class, I declared a method called displayNode to print out the data of the node. similarly, in the Linked-list class, I implemented a method to print out the data of the connected nodes in the linked list. However, while compiling, I get this error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method displayNode() is undefined for the type Node

```
at ds.linkedlist.SinglyLinkedList.displayList(SinglyLinkedList.java:33)
at ds.linkedlist.app.main(app.java:12)
```

[Node and linkedlist classes](https://gist.github.com/cirussaeb/90e2ab6ce6ce86e8b41f2a13ba772e31#file-gistfile1-txt)
[app class, that contains Main to execute the mentioned classes](https://gist.github.com/cirussaeb/7bc3ac620fea134c54e22534e1a719af)

though I copied both codes(Node and linked-list classes) in the same place they are actually implemented in different class files but the same package.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the source code here, not at places where the source code could be deleted.

Comment: sorry the linked list and node class implementation link is here: https://gist.github.com/cirussaeb/90e2ab6ce6ce86e8b41f2a13ba772e31

Comment: Not "here" in the comments, but in the actual question instead... Use the "edit" link to edit your question to include the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class [`Node`](https://gist.github.com/cirussaeb/90e2ab6ce6ce86e8b41f2a13ba772e31#file-gistfile1-txt) defines `displayNode()` such:

```
public displayNode()
```

You've probably overseen a compilation error, for you need to specify the return type (e.g. `void`).

Comment: yeah, i just saw that. a silly mistake! thank you very much